# Laravel middleware use carbon

Tags: php, laravel

I have middleware where I need to restrict user access if certain date has passed but the functionality doesn't work as expected

#### Code

```
class PaidMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $invoices = Invoice::where('paid', false)->get();
        $now = Carbon::today();
        foreach($invoices as $invoice){
            if(Auth::id() == $invoice->user_id && $invoice->end->isAfter($now)){
                return redirect()->route('forbidden');
            } else {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### Logic

1. If Auth `user id` is same as `user_id` column in `invoices` table
2. and if invoice row isn't mark as `paid`
3. then check `end` column and if that date is passed redirect user to forbidden page, otherwise let him/her do their activities.

#### Question

Which part of my code I did mistake?

> **Note** `end` column is `date` and not `dateTime` could that be the issue?

Comment: you have an if else return in your foreach loop. You'll never hit the second item in your array

Comment: Just a note, you can reduce the number of results by passing those fields in: `->where('user_id', Auth::id())` and even `->where('end', '>', Carbon::now())`

Comment: @Juakali92 even with removing else part still i can see the view instead of redirecting

Comment: @aynber i try it and let you know

Comment: @aynber still loads the view, not redirecting

Comment: Wouldn't the logic be the other way? If `end` is before Now, so 2020-04-06 would be before 2020-04-07.

Comment: @aynber did that already, didn't work

Comment: You might have to do some logging within the middleware to make sure it's hitting everything, such as `Log::info(__LINE__);` on several lines to see which lines it's hitting and `Log::info("Is $invoice->end before ".$now->toDateTimeString());` before your `if` line.

Comment: All logging lines will be found in files in `/storage/logs`

Comment: @aynber found the issue man, there was user_id difference appreciate your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove that **else condition**, not sure if that was your problem

```php
class PaidMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $invoices = Invoice::where('paid', false)->get();
        $now = Carbon::today();
        foreach($invoices as $invoice){
            if(Auth::id() == $invoice->user_id && $invoice->end->isAfter($now)){
                return redirect()->route('forbidden');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: it still loads the view (my end date is 2020-04-01)

Comment: @mafortis  shouldnt it than be $invoice->end->isBefore($now) ?

Comment: i did try that still view loads :/

Comment: Is your middleware in your $middlewares ? also is your Auth::id() returning any value? maybe it is called before checking user

Comment: my middleware is registered yes, about auth id i'm not sure, how can i check that?

Comment: for example dd(Auth::id()), also you can access user with $request->user()->id , maybe thats the problem

Comment: hold on :) i think the id's are different :))) my logged id and invoice user id are different :/

Comment: my apologies man, it's working just fine with your edit, thank you